# Detect Screen Rotation on Native Lock App

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, orientation

I am building an app with a Web based UI with separate "pages" built in on html file using divs.

After doing some research I found I couldn't enable and disable lock orientation through JS as I need 90% of my page divs to be locked to portrait but one of them I want to be able to rotate as the device is rotated.

So I have locked to portrait in the Native shell app want to know can I in HTML JS or jQuery detect the device rotation to landscape and hide one div and show another?

Thanks
D

Comment: Can't you just detect a window width change?

Comment: I tired that, but didnt seem to work. I may not have used it correctly can you point me to any resources/reference? I couldnt find any info on Stack or rest of web.